# Java Code Sample of Class reflection Example

Tags: java

I'm a college student studying Java.

While studying Java sample code and I met a code that did not work

When I excuted code then  The  console window nothing happens.
I don't know why doesn't work
I would appreciate it if you let me know.
Thank you for reading.

***environment***

OS: Window7

IDE:Eclipse

JAVA version : 1.8.0_181

**ShowClassInfo.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ShowClassInfo {
    public void printShow() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Class c = Class.forName("ShowClassInfo");
            System.out.println("==== Superclass ====");
            Class cla = c.getSuperclass();
            System.out.println(cla.toString());
            System.out.println("==Constructor []  ==");
            Constructor[] ctor = c.getConstructors();
            for(int i=0; i<ctor.length; i++) 
                System.out.println(ctor[i].toString());
            System.out.println("==== Method[] ====");
            Method[] m = c.getMethods();
            for(int i=0; i<m.length; i++)
                System.out.println(m[i].toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {}

    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `catch(Exception e) {}` with `catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}`. At the moment, if your code fails, you will never know... Since you are a beginner, keep in mind that swallowing exceptions (that is, catching exceptions and doing nothing), is usually bad practice, since it makes finding errors more difficult.

Comment: Do you not have a package?

Comment: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**: ShowClassInfo
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at TIL_2018_10_25.ShowClassInfo.main(ShowClassInfo.java:11)

Comment: When I added code -> catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} then I got an Exception above this

Comment: Rule of thumb: never have an empty `catch` block.  Either deal with the exception, or at the very least, log it.

Comment: I solve this problem!!!!! The problem was that I didn't write the name of package in `Class c = Class.forName("ShowClassInfo");`   The right code is `Class c = Class.forName("**packageName**.ShowClassInfo");`